# Python reads only the formula from excel cell

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a excel 2010 file which has cells (See C2 below in formula bar) with formulae. (Screenshot 1 below)

[image]

I am reading the value using python and it's printing the formula instead of actual value of the cell (Screenshot below of eclipse console.)

[image]

I want the results to print 10.188.11.184 which is the value populated by the formula of the excel cell. How can this be achieved? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read Excel cell value and not the formula computing it -openpyxl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517508/read-excel-cell-value-and-not-the-formula-computing-it-openpyxl)

Answer (score 12):

From:
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook

data_only controls whether cells with formulae have either the formula (default) or the value stored the last time Excel read the sheet.

```
wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx', data_only=True)
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your answer, and format code explicitly.

Comment: But when it saves the file, my formulas are gone from the excel sheet !! is there a way to leave the cells with formulas alone? i am not updating those cells anyways.

Comment: "it saves the files"? what is "it"? Please provide a complete minimal example.(code)

Comment: def update_driver_excel(fullFilePathOfDriverExcel):
    wb = load_workbook(fullFilePathOfDriverExcel, data_only=True)
    first_sheet = wb.get_active_sheet()
    for x in range(2,12):
        ipAddressOfMc = first_sheet.cell(row=x,column=3).value
        print(ipAddressOfMc)
        if(isUp(ipAddressOfMc)):
            first_sheet.cell(row=x,column=4).value = 1
            wb.save(fullFilePathOfDriverExcel)
        else:
            first_sheet.cell(row=x,column=4).value = 0
    wb.save(fullFilePathOfDriverExcel)
    print("Done updating the driver.")

Comment: Sorry no formatting possible above, so if you see i implemented date_inly=True above, and finally i am doing wb.save. after that when i opened the excel file, my formulae were gone.

Comment: Have you tried opening two Workbooks (one with data_only for reading values, one without for editing and saving)?

Comment: In openpyxl you can **either** have the formulae **or** the results of evaluating them. This is because the formulae themselves are never evaluated so their stability cannot be guaranteed. If you need both then you may be best scripting an application that can evaluate them. xlwings, http://xlwings.org/, might be useful here.

Comment: Charlie, you are right, python removes the formulas from the excel file on workbook.save(). I am going to stick to openpyxl for now, i will use a backup of the main excel every time i start the execution. may be shift to xlwings later. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xlrd module and do the reading easily.

```
read_fullreport = xlrd.open_workbook(report_to_read)
read_fullreport_sheet = read_fullreport.sheet_by_index(0)
ipAddressofMC = read_fullreport_sheet.cell_value(row_nr, col_nr)
```