# How to copy a range from one sheet to another as values using openpyxl in python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, worksheet

I have to copy a range from A1:Z100 from sheet onw of workbook 1 to sheet 1 of workbook 2?

My code :

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('file1.xlsx')
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('file2.xlsx')
sheet = wb["R"]
sheet1 = wb1["Rt"]
sheet1.cell(row=1,column=1).value = sheet.cell(row=1,column=1).value
```

This is not working properly. How to copy this range to that sheet?

Comment: What is not working? You are currently copying the value of only one cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with something like:

```
for i in range(1, 100):
    for j in range(1, 26):
        sheet1.cell(row=i,column=j).value = sheet.cell(row=i,column=j).value
wb1.save('file2.xlsx')
```

Comment: what is srcfile?

Comment: How can i copy only values and not with formulas?

Comment: Can this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50941203/how-to-copy-a-cell-value-instead-of-a-formula-from-excel-using-python

Comment: @Joe range(1:100) will not work use range(1,100) instead

Answer (score 5):

Giving another way to do using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
excel = pd.read_excel('file1.xlsx', header=None)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('file2.xlsx')
excel.loc[:99, :25].to_excel(writer, 'sheet1', index=False, header=False)
```

Add an openpyxl solution with data-only

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('file1.xlsx', data_only=True)
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('file2.xlsx')
sheet = wb['R']
sheet1 = wb1['Rt']
for row in sheet['A1':'Z100']:
    for cell in row:
        sheet1[cell.coordinate].value = cell.value
wb1.save('file2.xlsx')
```

**EDIT**

cell.coordinate returns value like 'A1' ,then sheet1['A1'].value is the value of cell A1

Comment: sheet1[cell.coordinate].value what this does?

Comment: @qwww cell.coordinate returns value like 'A1' ,then sheet1['A1'].value is the value of cell A1