# Use openpyxl to save outputs of cell given list of inputs

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Imagine a very simple problem:

- Column A has a list of values (say A1: 1, A2: 2, A3: 3)
- Cell C1 is a simple formula (say B1^2)

I wat to iterate the values in A, giving them to B1 each at a time, and save the results in a new list.

```python
    for idx in range(number_inputs):
        input_cell = f'A{(1+idx)}'
        target_cell = f'D{(1+idx)}'

        sheet['B1'] = sheet[input_cell].value
        sheet[target_cell] = sheet['C1'].value
```

The problem is that I cannot copy the value of C1, only the formula. [The solution to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517508/read-excel-cell-value-and-not-the-formula-computing-it-openpyxl) seems to be to load the workbook with the option `data_only=True`, but this does not work for me, since I need the formula in B1.

I was trying inelegant and desperate solutions, like copying my sheet to a new one... but this also copies the formulas.

Frankly, this seems like a surprisingly hard thing to do given how basic the goal is. Is there anything I am missing, or is this impossible to achieve?

Comment: Open the workbook a second-time using read-only, data-only parameters.

Comment: The problem is that this won't have the values updated as I try new inputs in the first instance, right?

Comment: openpyxl never updates calculations so you could never have that anyway. It's a file-format library, not an Excel replacement.

Comment: Then I assume what I want is not really possible to do. In the line of your advice I could create a new Excel file to save and load (as value-only) at every iteration. Not pretty, to be sure, but I guess it should work...

Comment: You might want to look at xlwings, which can talk to Excel while a file is open. Otherwise, changing data in openpyxl and passing to Excel or OpenOffice is the way to go.

Comment: I don't know if thanking in comments is also frowned upon, but thank you for taking the time!

Comment: You're welcome. If you can't write that kind of the stuff in the comments, where can you?