# Differences between xlwings vs openpyxl Reading Excel Workbooks

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlwings

I've mostly only used xlwings to open (`read-write`) workbooks (since the workbooks I read have complicated macros). But I've recently begun using openpyxl to open (`read-only`) workbooks when I've needed to read thousands of workbooks to scrape some data.

I've noticed that there is a considerable difference between how xlwings and openpyxl read workbooks. I believe xlwings relies on `pywin32` to read workbooks. When you read a workbook with `xlwings.Book(<filename>)` the actual workbook opens up. I have a feeling this is a result of `pywin32`.

However, when using `openpyxl.load_workbook(<filename>)` a workbook window does not appear. I have a feeling this is a result of not using `pywin32`.

Beyond this, I've no further understanding how the backends work for each libraries. Could someone shine some light on this? Is there a benefit/cost to relying on `xlwings` and `pywin32` for reading workbooks, as opposed to `openpyxl` which does not seem to use `pywin32`?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You are correct in that [`xlwings`](https://docs.xlwings.org) relies on [`pywin32`](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32), whereas [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io) does not.

### openpyxl

A ".xlsx" excel file is essentially a zip-file containing multiple XML files formatted according to Microsoft's [OOXML specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML). With this specification it's possible to create a program capable of directly reading/writing excel files in just about any programming language. This is the approach applied in `openpyxl`: it uses python code to read/write excel files directly.

### xlwings

A Microsoft Excel application can be started and controlled by an external program through the [Win32 COM API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/component-object-model--com--portal). The `pywin32` package provides an interface between Win32 COM and Python. Through a python script with the right pywin32 commands you can fully control an Excel Application (open excel files, query data from cells, write data to cells, save excel files, etc.). The `pywin32` commands that you can use mirror the [Excel VBA commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/excel), albeit with python syntax.

`xlwings` is (among other things) a user-friendly wrapper around `pywin32`. It introduces several concise-yet-powerful methods. An example would be the methods for direct [conversion](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/datastructures.html#numpy-arrays) of an excel cell range to a numpy array or pandas dataframe (and vice versa).

### Summary

A fundamental difference between `xlwings` and `openpyxl` is that the former requires that MS Excel is installed on your machine, whereas the latter does not.

Comment: What a great answer. Thanks!

Comment: I would like to add here that openpyxl doesn't have a comfortable support for calculating formulas (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517508/read-excel-cell-value-and-not-the-formula-computing-it-openpyxl?rq=1)), if you need to read or calculate formula results, xlwings is easier to use in this regard. However, regarding speed, it seems that openpyxl is faster. That's my personal impression.

Comment: I guess you inverted former and later in your last paragraph.

Comment: No, I did not invert openpyxl and xlwings. I am saying that using xlwings is usally a bit slower at the start, because Microsoft Excel starts in the background, whereas openpyxl directly changes the file without using Microsoft Excel in the background (if you work just with one or two excel files this time difference can be overlooked usually though). And whenever you need to work with formula results, I recommend xlwings.