# is it possible to insert a excel formula value not formula

Tags: python, excel

i am trying to insert a value using excel formula which is happening successfully but i want to save the value not formula ,here is the piece of code i am trying so far.

```
print("Adding formula to " + filename)         


for i,cellObj in enumerate(sheet_formula['P'],1):
        cellObj.value='=IF(AND(OR(A{0}="g_m",A{0}="s_m"),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("A", E{0}))), "A", VLOOKUP(A{0},\'i ma\'!A:B, 2, FALSE))'.format(i)
        sheet_formula.cell(row=1, column=16).value = 'C'
```

this piece of is able to insert formula but i want to save the value not formula

Comment: Not sure if this would work on Python, but in VBA when you want to convert a formula into a value, we do `cell.value=cell.value`. Have you tried adding `cellObj.value=cellObj.value` after inserting the formula?

Comment: thanks for your help but it is not working

Comment: Are you using any additional libraries besides `win32com`? I'm getting **'_Worksheet' object is not subscriptable**. Or is `sheet_formula` something other than a worksheet?

Comment: Also, the property names appear to be case sensitive, e.g. `Value` and not `value`.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, it kind of works just like that with the right library =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"The basic reasons for abandoning openpyxl are: (1) XLS file processing is not supported; (2) the bug of testing current version style preservation is not solved; If you encounter the above two problems, give up openpyxl and embrace xlwings. There is no way out."* **Grabbed from [here](https://developpaper.com/give-up-openpyxl-and-embrace-xlwings-python-operates-xls/)**.

---

> *"It's possible using `xlwings` which uses pywin32 objects to interact with Excel, rather than just reading/writing xlsx or csv documents like openpyxl and pandas. This way, Excel actually executes the formula, and xlwings grabs the result."* **Grabbed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44790084/9758194)**.

---

So while it's **not** possible (so it seems) using just `Openpyxl`, or any other library that does not support xls file processing, as a Python library, it is possible using `xlwings`. I have added a simple sample below. I simply opened a fresh workbook, added a formula and transformed the formula to it's calculated value.

```
import xlwings as xw
app = xw.App(visible=False, add_book=False)
wb = app.books.add()
ws = wb.sheets.active
ws['A1'].value = '=3+5'
ws['A1'].value = ws['A1'].value
wb.save(r'C:\Users\...\test.xlsx')
wb.close()
app.quit()
exit()
```

Hopefully the above helps. Please keep in mind; I'm a Python beginner!

---

For those who are interested, some good explaination about the difference between `Openpyxl` and `xlWings` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58331928/9758194). And a somewhat similar problem with some answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28517508/9758194)

Comment: `ws['A1'].value = ws['A1'].value` Yes, I was sure there was something similar! LoL