# openpyxl help - Cannot get excel right trim working

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to use the "=Right(A1,8)" Excel function in my python openpyxl file but all it does is place the formula text into the cell.

What am I doing wrong?

File info:
I have a working file where I need to read and extract text from cell A1, (Exact Text in A1 is SITE:SC05100A)  I want to strip off the "SITE:" portion and save the remainder in cell B4.  In the spreadsheet I use `"=RIGHT(A1,8)"` which returns "SC05100A".
However when I try to use that in my python script it simply puts the formula string into the cell.

Cell A1 value is SITE:SC05100A
Cell B4 is currently empty.

Python code entered is:

```
        ws['B4'].value = '=Right(A1,8)'
        print ('A1 value is: ',ws['A1'].value)
        print ('B4 value is: ',ws['B4'].value)
```

when I run the code I get no errors and output shows:

```
        A1 value is:  SITE: SC05100A
        B4 value is:  =RIGHT(A1,8)
        [Finished in 677ms]
```

Yes, I have tried it without the 'B4 value is: ' portion, but as you can see that works as well.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Openpyxl doesn't evaluate formula. If you open your excel file, you'll see that excel is evaluating the formula properly. If you wanted to see the evaluated value, use `xlwings` (you do need Excel installed for this to work)

```
import openpyxl as op 
import xlwings as xw

# Create workbook, add data
wb = op.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws['A1'].value = "ABCDEFG"
ws['B1'].value = '=Right(A1, 3)'

# Save workbook
wb.save("test.xlsx")

# Reopen with xlwings
wbxw = xw.Book("test.xlsx")
print ('B1 value is: ', wbxw.sheets['Sheet'].range('B1').value)
```

Comment: have never heard of xlwings before.  Looks like it needs to be pip installed before I can give it a try.    What is the difference between openpyxl and xlwings?

Comment: Openpyxl directly reads and writes the xlsx files, whereas xlwings uses excel itself to open and read/wite files (this is why using xlwings opens an excel window). A more thorough explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58331928/12664040). And yes it needs to be pip installed