# python script to paste rows from 1 excel sheet to another. Paste should be "paste by value"

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl, xlsxwriter, xlrd

I am writing a python script to copy rows and columns from source to destination excel sheet.
Source excel sheet has rows that have formulas. I just want to copy and paste values instead of the formula. Is there some way to do that in python?
I have written the below code (it copies and paste the formulas instead of the actual value)

```
file_src="C:\\Users\\final_excel1.xlsx"
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_src)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[2] # index=n-1

file_dest = "C:\\Users\\final_excel2.xlsx"
wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_dest) 
ws2 = wb2.active

r_ws1=ws1.max_row
c_ws1=ws1.max_column

## copying values from source to dest.
for i in range  (1, req_r_ws1+1):
    for j in range (1, req_c_ws1+1):
        cell=ws1.cell(row=i, column=j)
        ws2.cell(row=i, column=j).value=cell.value

wb2.save(file_dest)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add data_only=True to wb1

```
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_src, data_only=True)
```

also see, [Read Excel cell value and not the formula computing it -openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517508/read-excel-cell-value-and-not-the-formula-computing-it-openpyxl)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was looking exactly for the same.