# Python openpyxl: How can I compute the cells when the value of them are functions or equations？

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to compute data from some excel files by using the library `openpyxl`.

And am now in trouble with the cell.value of functions or equations.

eg:

I may have such two `cell.value` below:

```
ws = openpyxl.load_work(xl_path)['Sheet1']
print(ws['B1'].value)
print(ws['B2'].value)
```

```
[output:]
= A1+A2    # Actually, the true value may be 1(A1) + 2(A2) -> 3
= A2*A4    # Actually, the true value may be 1(A1) * 4(A4) -> 4
```

And when I compute it , I got is not what I want:

```
ws['C1'].value = ws['B2'].value + ws['B1'].value 
print(ws['C1'].value)
```

I got a string result that concat `str format` value of this two cell.value:

```
[output:]
= A1+A2= A2*A4
```

I know some methods to get the true value of cells not functions or equations by using some 3rd party library , such as `pandas`.

But I wanna search a way just use the `openpyxl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to operate with the actual values, and not formulae, with OpenPyXl is by opening that workbook with

`load_workbook(xl_path, data_only = True)`

This will open the exact same workbook but all cells will only be have their calculated values.

[Read Excel cell value and not the formula computing it -openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517508/read-excel-cell-value-and-not-the-formula-computing-it-openpyxl)