# How to combine value in multiple cell references in Excel by Python?

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, concatenation

I am trying to do something like grabbing all values in each cell while they are referencing one by one. Maybe an example help illustration.

Example:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| =B2 | ='I am' & C2 | 'Peter |

Example2 - in term of number:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| =B2 | =C2*D2 | 12 | 56 |

So I want to get a `concat` string 'I am Peter' or 672 (from 12*56) when I reading the `cell A2`

Code I tried:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'new.xlsx')
sheet_names = wb.get_sheet_names()
name = sheet_names[0]
sheet_ranges = wb[name]
df = pd.DataFrame(sheet_ranges.values)
print(df)
```

The formula will become `'NaN'`

Any suggestion to achieve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have the actual values of the cells, you have to use data_only=True

```
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'new.xlsx', data_only=True)
```

Look here: [Read Excel cell value and not the formula computing it -openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517508/read-excel-cell-value-and-not-the-formula-computing-it-openpyxl)

Anyway, as you use pandas, it would be way easier to go directly:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('new.xlsx')
print(df)
```

which grabs the first sheet (but could be specified) and gives the values as output.

Answer (score 0):

*openpyxl* supports either the formula or the value of the formula. You can select which using the `data_only` parameter when loading a workbook.

You can change your code like below:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

wb = load_workbook(filename='new.xlsx', data_only=True)
sheet_names = wb.get_sheet_names()
name = sheet_names[0]
sheet_ranges = wb[name]
df = pd.DataFrame(sheet_ranges.values)
print(df)
```