# How to remove a formula and keep only value in a cell using python

Tags: python, excel

I need to remove a formula from a cell in excel and keep the value
I have worksheet with many sheets(tabs) .In one of the
sheet I have 3 columns;
Date,
Expected usage,
Due in,
I need to be able to remove formula from "expected usage" and "due in" on certain dates form that particular worksheet(forecast_consumption_rate)
Just wondering if anyone could help

Comment: how are you accessing excel data from python? pandas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read Excel cell value and not the formula computing it -openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517508/read-excel-cell-value-and-not-the-formula-computing-it-openpyxl)