# How to save in openpyxl without losing formulae?

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

Because I need to parse and then use the actual data in cells, I open an xlsm in `openpyxl` with `data_only = True`.

This has proved very useful. Now though, having the same need for an xlsm that contains formuale in cells, when I then save my changes, the formulae are missing from the saved version.

Are `data_only = True` and formulae mutually exclusive? If not, how can I access the actual value in cells without losing the formulae when I save?

When I say I lose the formulae, it seems that the *results* of the formulae (sums, concatenattions etc.) get preserved. But the actual formulaes themselves are no longer displayed when a cell is clicked.

**UPDATE:**

To confirm whether or not the formulaes were being preserved or not, I've re-opened the saved xlsm, this time with `data_only` left as `False`. I've checked the `value` of a cell that had been constructed using a formula. Had formulae been preserved, opening the xlsm with data_only set to False should have return the formula. But it returns the actual text value (which is not what I want).

Comment: Python: 2.7.10. Openpyxl: latest.

Comment: Clicking on *Show Formulas* in Excel has no effect for such a saved spreadsheet.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to preserve the integrity of the workbook, ie. retain the formulae, the you cannot use `data_only=True`. The documentation makes this very clear.

Comment: The thing is: the integrity **does** seem to get maintained i.e. the cells contain the proper results of their original formulae. It's just that the formalue themselves don't get displayed when a cell is clicked on.

Comment: You have to choose: either the formulae or the values that result from their calculation. By integrity I mean that there is no guarantee that the values are still true because openpyxl itself never evaluates formulae.

Comment: Fair enough, and thanks for the additional clarification. Keep up the good work with this awesome library.

Answer (score 3):

Part of your question was: *Are `data_only = True` and formulae mutually exclusive?*

The answer to that, in openpyxl, is yes.

But this is not intrinsic to Excel. You *could* have a library like openpyxl which gives you access to both the formulas and their results. This is unlikely to happen, since the maintainer(s) of openpyxl are philosophically opposed to this idea.

So, how you're expected to handle your kind of situation in openpyxl is to load the workbook twice: once with `data_only=True` just to read the data (which you keep in memory), then load it again as a "different" workbook with `data_only=False` to get a writable version.

The "canonical" way of modifying an existing workbook with Python while preserving *everything* else (including formatting, formulas, charts, macros, etc.) is to use a COM interface (such as [PyWin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/), or higher-level wrappers like [pywinauto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywinauto) or [xlwings](http://xlwings.org/)) to control a running instance of Excel. Of course, this is only possible if you are running on a machine with Excel installed.