# Retrieve a value as a datetime with pandas (selected by filtering by rows / columns)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I need to save datetimes to an Excel file, such that, after reading the Excel file again, I can compare them with other datetimes. Here is a minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd, datetime
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2],
                   'B': [datetime.datetime(2000,1,1,1,2,3), 
                         datetime.datetime(2010,1,1,1,2,3)]})
df.to_excel('test.xlsx')                # save to Excel file
df2 = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')        # load from Excel file
print(df2)
t = df2.loc[df['A'] == 2, 'B']         # select the value in col B by filtering rows
L = [t, datetime.datetime(2020,1,1,1,2,3)]
print(sorted(L))
```

This gives the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

What's the standard `pandas` way to retrieve the value of `t` as a datetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need scalar from one element Series:

```
#select first value if always matched at least one row
t = df2.loc[df['A'] == 2, 'B'].iat[0]

#general solution for return default value if no match
t = next(iter(df2.loc[df['A'] == 2, 'B']), 'no match')
```

EDIT: If create index by `A` column by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and always matching value like here `2` and column `B` is possibe use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select by index nand columns names:

```
df = df2.set_index('A')
t = df.loc[2, 'B']
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. Isn't there a shorter way in the API to access to a value at a location obtained by row-filtering? Something like `df.value[df['A'] == 2, 'B']`? Here it seems unusually complex to have to `.loc[...].iat[...]`, don't you think so?

Comment: PS @jezrael: I mean without changing the index (I could filter on other columns than the index)

Comment: Thank you very much @jezrael. Since you are one of the top pandas gurus (pandas developer?), you might have an idea for this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66421693/modify-an-excel-file-with-pandas-with-minimal-change-of-the-layout I started a bounty, and a few ideas would be really great! Just in case, thanks :)

Comment: @Basj - Now not idea about another solution.