# Print sum value of a range with Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to print the value in the cell B26. So far all my print out is '=SUM(B2:B25)' for each iteration. How can I print the sum value in the range of B2:B25?

```
import glob
import openpyxl

path = 'C:/ExcelFolder/*.xlsx'
files = glob.glob(path)
for file in files:
  wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
  sheet2 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('TOTAL')
  Totals = sheet2.cell(row=26, column=2).value
  print(Totals)
```

Output is:

```
=SUM(B2:B25)
=SUM(B2:B25)
=SUM(B2:B25)
=SUM(B2:B25)
=SUM(B2:B25)
```

Comment: This is covered by the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
sheet2.cell(row=26, column=2).internal_value
```

update

```
import glob
import openpyxl

path = 'C:/ExcelFolder/*.xlsx'
files = glob.glob(path)
for file in files:
  wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file,data_only=True)
  sheet2 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('TOTAL')
  Totals = sheet2.cell(row=26, column=2).value
  print(Totals)
```

Comment: I still get the same output of '=SUM(B2:B25)'

Comment: @wisenhiemer  updated.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook) documentation, it seems like instead of

`Totals = sheet2.cell(row=26, column=2).value`

You'd want something like

`Totals = sheet2['B26'].value`

if you just want to read at that cell in an existing workbook.

Comment: I had tried this before and still got the same output.

Comment: Have you taken a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613272/how-to-access-the-real-value-of-a-cell-using-the-openpyxl-module-for-python

Comment: That worked! adding the 'data_only=True)'. Thank you!