# Pandas does NOT read values from Excel cells with such simple formula as =10+10

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I've got a few Excel sheets with columns with different data types.
Some of them consist of formulas as well.
Pandas **does NOT read values** from Excel cells with such simple formula as `=10+10` or `=250+30+40`

Code like this

```
truck_work = pd.read_excel(hauls_monthly_data, sheetname=truck)
```

returns dataframe where column filled from those Excel cells consists data, which type is **float** and value is **nan**.
But I'm waiting for **float** with value **10** and **320**

The only way I've worked out yet to solve this issue is by manually saving each time an Excel-file before processing data from it. Which is not much Pythonic way of dealing with problems.

If I'm using such code as

```
wb = load_workbook(filename = hauls_monthly_data)
sheet_names = wb.get_sheet_names()
name = sheet_names[1]
sheet_ranges = wb[name]
truck_work = pd.DataFrame(sheet_ranges.values)
```

then it returns

```
8          =16+109+108        =6+40+29                None
```

Any help be very appreciated.

Comment: The question was marked as 'duplicate'. But I can't catch what is a reason? The topic which is mentioned above as an answer actually was about an attempt to read formulas not values. I'm not able to read data as I need instead.

Comment: Yeah, your problem is the inverse of the marked duplicate. This one might be a better match:

Comment: Possible Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613272/how-to-access-the-real-value-of-a-cell-using-the-openpyxl-module-for-python?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @divibisan Maybe I was not clear enough with my question. But the answer mentioned above does not consist of methods to solve my issue. Any of them. By using 'wb = load_workbook(filename = hauls_monthly_data)' I got '=16+109+108 ' for all cells with such data. If I use 'wb = load_workbook(filename = hauls_monthly_data, data_only=True)' then it returns 'None'. But I do need a float value of those cells, the result of that simple calculation which in this particular cell is 233.

Comment: Then you should edit your question to show what happens when you try the suggestions in the linked question. By editing your question it will be put in the `reopen` queue and will get reopened once people see how it is, in fact, different from that question