# I want to read a cell value, not its formula

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm using openPyXl library and I'd like to store a cell value, not its formula.
In the cell that I want to read there's the formula

```
=COUNTIF(C4:C21,"M")
```

and it returns 0, but when I read it from python

```
read=sheet['C28'].value
```

it returns me again =COUNTIF(C4:C21,"M"). And if i try with simply

```
read=sheet['C28']
```

It returns me

```
<Cell 'Sheet1'.C28>
```

How could I get 0?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [How to access the real value of a cell using the openpyxl module for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613272/how-to-access-the-real-value-of-a-cell-using-the-openpyxl-module-for-python)
when loading the workbook you have to set data_only to True: `wb = load_workbook("file.xlsx", data_only=True)`