# Cant open cells using openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to work with openpyxl following a Programming with Mosh Python course. I can't open cells when using the `.cell` method. This happens for me when calling the cell by string as well. Any help welcome. Thank you.

Here's my code:

```
import openpyxl as xl
wb = xl.load_workbook('transactions.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
cell = sheet.cell(1, 1)
print(cell)
# prints <Cell 'Sheet'.A1> without actual cell information
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the real value of a cell using the openpyxl module for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613272/how-to-access-the-real-value-of-a-cell-using-the-openpyxl-module-for-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.value` to get information from a cell. Here is the corrected code:

```
import openpyxl as xl
wb = xl.load_workbook('transactions.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
cell = sheet.cell(1, 1)
print(cell.value)
```

Comment: I now realize I wasn't paying enough attention to the video, Apologies.

Comment: @JakeSnell It's fine, we all make mistakes! If you benefited from my answer, please mark it as the accepted answer.